# Standard New Button overwritten with VF to default values in Lead Object not openinig in SF1

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, urlhacking

We are using Lead Object and 'Company' field in not required for our users to fill . To minimize user effort ,url hacking was used and company is defaulted to 'XYZ'. This works fine in Desktop  but breaks in SF1 and tries to open the page outside mobile app .

```
pgRef = new PageReference('/00Q/e?lea3='+system.label.Prospect_Generic_Account+'&name_lastlea2=New     Prospect'+'&retURL=%2F00Q%2Fo'+'&nooverride=1');
```

Please help how can I get this working in SF1 .

Thanks in Advance .

Anwesha

Answer (score 1):

URL hacking is not supported in Salesforce 1. So you can't use this.

Instead you can use [createRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_dev_jsapi_sforce_one.htm) from sforce library. It allow you to give default values to field.

```
sforce.one.createRecord(​entityName​, [recordTypeId], [defaultFieldValues])
```

Comment: We are not using lightning . Can I use this for classic as well .

Comment: Prospect  is standard page and not VF . Do you recommend then to convert the prospect to VF ?

Comment: @AnweshaCloudX This will work for SF1 as well. I don't think we need custom VF page here.